# txt file delete in directory

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off & setlocal
cd Your_Folder
for %%j in (*.txt) do type "%%j" | find /I "stackoverflow" > nul || del "%%j"
```

1.The above code will serach for the word "stackoverflow" in the text files kept in the folder.But  how to do the same thing for the text files kept in the directory

Comment: What's the difference between a folder and a directory?

Comment: if you mean in a root directory of another drive, try this `pushd d:\ `

Comment: I'm guessing you want to know how to get any files that are in subdirectories?

Comment: Scott, technically the difference is that a folder is what Explorer shows as a container, which may or may not refer to a filesystem location (a directory). For example the Control Panel is a folder but not a directory. I doubt the definition applies in their question, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you're trying to find a word in a text-based file somewhere in your directory you could try using something like this:

```
 findstr /S /M yoursearchword "C:\Top Directory\*"
```

The /M will print the files that have that name in it. The /S is needed along with the * to search in all sub-directories.